# How can i fill a 2d ArrayBuffer in a dynamic way only in one dimension?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, arraybuffer

i want to have `(id, ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Double]])` filled from a `Dstream batch`. My input data is of the form: `"id, counter, value"` and each id has more than one values per counter in each RDD. 
So what i want is:

```
       +-------+-----+------+----+
       |      |value1|value2|etc |
       +-------------------------+
 (id,  |count1|0.2   |0.3   |    |)
       |count2|0.1   |      |    |
       |etc   |      |      |    |
       +------+------+------+----+
```

When i get the `RDD input`, i know the counter dimension but i don't know how many values i have stored in each counter to fill the next empty cell. I tried to create an `Array[Array[Double]]` with a `findNextEmpty()` method but i get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so i am trying `ArrayBuffer` after that. Is there any way to fill dynamically only one of the dimensions of a 2d ArrayBuffer?

My code is:

```
var example = inputRdd.transform(x =>
       x.groupBy(_ (0))
       .mapValues(x => x
       .foldLeft( ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Double]]) { (a, b) => {
        a(b(1).toInt)(??) += b(2).toDouble //Don't know the second dimension             
         }}))
```

Comment: Why mutate in foldLeft?
Instead, you can use a `List[List[Double]]`, right?
`foldLeft(List[List[Double]]()) {((a,b) => List(b) :: a)}`

Comment: Is it wrong? Can you explain why list would be a better option in this case?

Comment: So you are mutating the array, usually I would keep things completly immutable and you are making foldLeft a impure function by mutating things.